# How to sync a dynamic property from a parent component to a child component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I have some products that I want to filter based on their category using checkboxes.

To do so, I have a parent component which passes the possible categories (e.g. A, B and C) to the child and keeps track of the checked/selected categories.

However, the tricky part is that the possible categories are dynamic: sometimes the array of categories may shrink or grow.

This results in incorrect behaviour due to the booleans of the checkboxes not corresponding anymore to the correct positions. For example, the first two checkboxes are checked, but whenever the array changes, the first two values are still checked (which are now different values). This is demonstrated here:

[Vue Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

I managed to solve the issue by letting the child keep track of the checkboxes itself with a local property and emit to the parent whenever updated. However, if I add a second child then child 1 and child 2 are not synced anymore (for example when I would use 1 filter in the mobile menu and 1 in the normal menu). This is shown here:

[Vue Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

So both solutions are not optimal yet and any help is appreciated for this puzzle!

Below is the simplified code. Whenever the minimal-price filter changes, the FilterOptions array only shows the possible categories of products that meet the price criteria. When this happens, the positions do not correspond anymore to the correct values.

**Child Component - FilterCheckboxItem.vue**

```
<template>

<div
  v-for="(FilterOption, index) in FilterOptions"
> 
  <label for="lname">{{FilterOption}}</label>   
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :value="FilterOption"
    v-model="modelValue[index]"
  />
</div>


</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
     FilterOptions: {
      type: Array,
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: Array,
    },
 },
}
</script>
```

**Parent Component**

```
<template>


  <FilterCheckboxItem
    ref="Category"
    name="Category"
    :FilterOptions="CategoriesWithinPriceReq"
    v-model="FilteredCategories"
  />


<input v-model="MinimalPrice">

</template>

<script>
import FilterCheckboxItem from './Comp.vue'
export default {
  components: { FilterCheckboxItem },
  data(){
    return {
      FilteredCategories: [],
      CategoryOptions: ["A","B","C"],
      MinimalPrice: 5,

      Products: 
        [
        {name: 'test1', price: 10, category: "A"},
        {name: 'test2', price: 15, category: "B"},
        {name: 'test3', price: 20, category: "C"},
        {name: 'test4', price: 8, category: "C"}

        ]  
    }
  },

  computed: {
    FilteredProducts: function(){
    return this.filterProductsByCategory(this.filterProductsByPrice(this.Products))
    },
    CategoriesWithinPriceReq: function(){
      let CategoriesMeetingFilter = this.filterProductsByPrice(this.Products);
      
 
      let uniqueCatgeoriesMeetingFilters = [
        ...new Set(CategoriesMeetingFilter.map(({ category }) => category)),
      ];
      return uniqueCatgeoriesMeetingFilters;
      
    },
  },

  methods: {
    filterProductsByPrice: function(products){
      return products.filter((product)=>product.price>=this.MinimalPrice)
      },
    filterProductsByCategory: function(products){
      const selected_categories = this.CategoriesWithinPriceReq.filter((category, bool) => this.FilteredCategories[bool])
      const results = products.filter((product) => selected_categories.indexOf(product.category) !==-1)
      // Only filter if atleast one box is checked, otherwise return all products
      return selected_categories && selected_categories.length? results: products
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each child updates `FilteredCategories` through the `v-model`:

```html
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <FilterCheckboxItem
    :FilterOptions="CategoriesWithinPriceReq"
    v-model="FilteredCategories"
  />

    <div>Child 2</div>
  <FilterCheckboxItem
    :FilterOptions="CategoriesWithinPriceReq"
    v-model="FilteredCategories"
  />
```

When one of the components updates the variable, the other one has to update the checked state of its checkboxes. So it has to react to incoming changes. You can easily do this with a watcher:

```
// FilterCheckboxItem.vue
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    ...
    watch(
      () => props.modelValue, 
      () => checked.value = props.modelValue
    )
    ...
  },
```

Here is the [updated playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

---

However, this will cause the child component to update an array which is passed from the parent (the `modelValue` from the prop goes to `checked`, which is updated by the checkboxes). This is considered poor form. Due to the watcher on `checked`, it is not possible to just use a copy of `modelValue` (i.e. `checked.value = [...props.modelValue]`), as it leads to an endless loop (setting `checked` leads to an emit, which updates `modelValue`, which sets `checked` again).

The way around it is to only emit when checkboxes are clicked by setting an `@input` handler. Since you are using the checkbox array mode of `v-model`, you have to wait until the array is updated before emitting:

```html
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :value="filterOption"
    v-model="checked"
    @input="emitOnNextCycle"
  />
```

and

```
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const checked = ref([]);
    const emitOnNextCycle = () => setTimeout(() => emit('update:modelValue', checked.value))
    watch(
      () => props.modelValue, 
      () => checked.value = [...props.modelValue]
    )
    return { checked, emitOnNextCycle };
  },
```

See [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Instead of `setTimeout()` you could also use `nextTick()` or `Promise.resolve()`, they all do the same in this case.

---

There is a third option, where you don't use a local copy at all, but instead pass on data and events directly. This does not work with `v-model`, you have to use the underlying data binding and event, usually `:modelValue` and `@update:modelValue`, but since you are working with native checkboxes, it is `:checked` and `@input` and you have to write your own array mode:

```html
<!-- in template -->
<input
  type="checkbox"
  :checked="modelValue.includes(filterOption)"
  @input="event => onInput(filterOption, event.target.checked)"
/>
```

and

```
setup(props, { emit }) {
  const onInput = (option, isChecked) => {
    const selection = props.modelValue.filter(selectedOption => selectedOption !== option)
    if (isChecked){
      selection.push(option)
    }
    emit('update:modelValue', selection)
  }
  return {onInput}
}
```

Now the component does not an internal state anymore, the `:checked` prop reacts directly to changes to `modelValue`, and `@input` just emits the update event. This is probably the easiest solution, but it is not always possible.

[playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

---

As a tip, avoid mixing options API elements and setup function, it is confusing and leads to unclear behavior.
Also, the vast majority of JS programmers uses camelCase for variables names, PascalCase is reserved for classes and types. Make of that what you will.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and also learned a lot due to the clear explanation, thanks! Two small things I am still wondering: 1: Why is the second solution better form than the first? Technically with the second solution the child is also modifying an array which is passed from the parent, right? 2: The syntax of the watcher is a bit confusing, the first part before the comma is the 'getter' as I understand it from the documentation. Why is the part after the comma also formatted as a function, should it always be like that ?

Comment: That's great. Thank you for the kind feedback! In the second solution, the watcher creates a copy of the array, so changing `checked` does not change the array in the parent (disable the emit to see that it works on a local copy). The advantage is that the state of the parent does not change implicitly, but only through emits, which gives you a clearer structure. It is also [recommended in the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props). I try to stick to it, as it is usually not hard to do and improves readability.

Comment: With the watcher, the second part is the callback that is executed when the watched value changes. While the first part can also be a ref or an array, the callback is always a function, yes.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I read in your link that the best practise is to always let a child emit an event when modifying the parent. Technically the first solution is also doing that, but I think I understand what you mean: In the second solution they are less coupled because the child is only emiting the event on input change instead of continously watching the child array and always updating. It that what is meant?

Comment: This is me being a stickler, but I think the idea is that the child never modifies the parent, but instead emits updated data and have the parent figure it out. So even when emitting an event along with changing parent data directly, it would still be bad practice. However, since you are using v-model's special array mode on checkboxes, which creates a new array on every change, the first solution actually works fine, it just looks bad.

Comment: Overall, the example with checkboxes and array mode is very particular, bringing parent state mutation into it makes it even more confusing. I hope you find it still helpful. I have added a third option to the answer, that circumvents the issue completely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the info, helps a lot in understanding